# Why does my script return "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get the profitability of every project by dividing profit by revenue.
The code is working, I get the values back.

I just need help with the last part (the dividing part). There is where I'm having some issues.

Here is my code.

The outcome I get is

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
from observations.constants import PROJECTS_DB_ID
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get(gs_client):
    #Sheet access
    sheet = gs_client.open_by_key(
        PROJECTS_DB_ID).worksheet('Finance')

    #Columns necessary
    projects = sheet.col_values(1)[2:]
    months = sheet.col_values(2)[2:]
    profit = sheet.col_values(11)[2:]
    revenue = sheet.col_values(6)[2:]
    last_modified = sheet.col_values(13)[2:]

    #Lists
    list_projects = []
    list_months = []
    list_profit = []
    list_revenue = []
    list_last_modified = []
    value = []

    #Gets each project
    for project in projects:
        list_projects.append(project)

    #Gets each month
    for month in months:
        list_months.append(month)

    #Gets each value of profit column
    for val in profit:
        list_profit.append(val.strip('$').replace(',',''))

    #Gets each value in revenue column
    for value in revenue:
        list_revenue.append(value.strip('$').replace(',',''))

    #Gets each date in last modified column
    for update in last_modified:
        list_last_modified.append(update)

    #Get profitability per project (profit divided by revenue)
    for x in range(len(projects)):
        value1 = float(list_profit[x])/float(list_revenue[x])
        value.append(value1)

    print(value)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which particular append is failing? You have a few there..

Comment: could you share at which line the error occurs?

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback. You should also read the guidance for reducing your problem to a [mre].

Comment: In your 4th `for` loop you're changing the type of `value` from `list` to `str`.

Comment: The error is in line 45

Comment: I resolved it guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is due to variable `value`, you have used it as list and as string.

```py
    #Lists
    list_projects = []
    list_months = []
    list_profit = []
    list_revenue = []
    list_last_modified = []
    value = []

    #Gets each project
    for project in projects:
        list_projects.append(project)

    #Gets each month
    for month in months:
        list_months.append(month)

    #Gets each value of profit column
    for val in profit:
        list_profit.append(val.strip('$').replace(',',''))

    #Gets each value in revenue column
    for val in revenue: # here, changed value to val
        list_revenue.append(val.strip('$').replace(',',''))

    #Gets each date in last modified column
    for update in last_modified:
        list_last_modified.append(update)

    #Get profitability per project (profit divided by revenue)
    for x in range(len(projects)):
        value1 = float(list_profit[x])/float(list_revenue[x])
        value.append(value1)
```

whenever you use `for i in somthing` in python, the i isn't local variable inside the for loop like in other language, value of i is the last value of i inside the loop, which can also be accessed after the end of the loop. You have to be very careful about the use of variable names in python.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. WIll be extra careful next time.

Comment: try to keep more descriptive variable names so you don't accidentally overwrite them.